# Escape character is not working in cshtml ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, escaping, character

I am referencing the tensorflow JavaScript in my `.cshtml` file. As referred by many online articles I am using `@` character as escape character, however that is not still not working. Please see the image below. Any help?

[image: Click here to see the image]

Thanks in advance.